# Background Images - I'm unable to remove, reposition, scale or change

Tags: interface

Currently I can place an image into the background, however I'm unable to remove, reposition, scale or change. I've tried a number of times including closing the blender and reopening. I'm able to change all the settings in a different file, just not on my current lesson.

Any support will be appreciated.

Using blender 2.79 on iMac Sierra 10.12.6

[image: Blender, can't change Background images]

Comment: in the gif you are operating on an image called "head_side..." maybe it's the other (side) image. Try on the upper one...(front ?)

Answer (score 3):

Its look like you are trying to add 2 images, 1 for the front view and 1 for the side view.

As per looking your screenshot and highlighted below #1 and #2. 1 is telling us that you are on the front view and #2 is telling that you are trying to adjust the side view of the picture.

If you want to adjust size and stuff for the Front image, please use the settings under the front view as marked #3 below. or if you want to adjust the size of the side view you may use the side view, hit <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Also more relevant than the image name, is that just under #2 it shows that the image is to only be visible in the right axis view.