# How to delete an image that was drag and dropped instead of added with Images as planes?

Tags: interface, image

i accidentally added an Image by drag and drop into 3d viewport instead of adding it with    add images as planes .It shows up only in orthographic view and in camera view but i can not select it and i don t see it in the Outliner.How can i delete it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background Images - I'm unable to remove, reposition, scale or change](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93876/background-images-im-unable-to-remove-reposition-scale-or-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Press N
- go to Background Image
- delete image
- END

[image: Background Image]

Comment: only 7 minutes from Question to Answer ,thank you a lot

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by deleting the camera in scene. After that add a new camera. At this point you need to place the new camera like the old one. Just move your view port to see the scene or model at the angle you want the new camera to capture your scene then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (on numpad). The camera will automatically set itself to your current viewport.